# How can i show the Box Plot of Only Certain Columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to see the boxplot of certain columns, say "Age", and "Credit_Balance".

When i use the below given code, it shows all numerical variables, how can i limit it to those two variables that i mentioned? Thanks in advance.

data.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(3,5), sharex=False, sharey=False,figsize=(15,8))

plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
df[['Age', 'Credit_Balance']].boxplot()
```

which yields for

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Income' : [3500, 4000, 1500, 7850, 2330, 3150, 2800],
                   'Age' : [29, 18, 45, 32, 78, 23, 67],
                   'Credit_Balance' : [45000, 34000, 113000, 37500, 13000, 5000, 0]})
```

the plot
[image]

that can subsequently be tuned.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to see it in different plots, not two together. Is it possible? Two separate tables, i mean

Comment: What about `df[['Age']].boxplot()` and  subsequently`df[[ 'Credit_Balance']].boxplot()`?